# Can't acces JSON data from FeedMe Feed

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying to load a JSON feed and parse/display the data.  My code below generates an error - "impossible to access id on a string variable".  Below is some sample JSON data I get back along with code I tried to use to display.  Any help accessing my JSON data would be hugely appreciated.

Code to load / display feed (does not work):

```
{% set params = {
    url: 'https://jsonURL',
    type: 'json',
    element: '',
    cache: 60,
} %}

{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}

{% for node in feed %}
    node: {{ node.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

JSON feed data:

```
{
    "id":"546852386",
    "timestamp":"2019-10-17 15:35:47",
    "user_agent":"Mozilla",
    "remote_addr":"1234",
    "payment_status":"",
    "form":"12345",
    "latitude":"123",
    "longitude":"123",
    "data":[
        {
            "field":"83628997","value":"first = aa\nlast = a"
        },
        {
            "field":"83691483",
            "value":"1"
        }
    ],
    "pretty_field_id":"83628997"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out ... I guess since I'm only getting one results I can't actually loop through.  Eg: the following works.

```
{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}
id: {{ feed.id }}
form: {{ feed.form }}
```